# jQuery: fadein and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table. Inside there are 4 images which should change their src on hover, returning to the original src when mouse is not on hover.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="social"><img src="files/img/fb_circle.png" data-src="files/img/fb_circle_hover2.png" /></a></td>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/" class="social"><img src="files/img/tw_circle.png" data-src="files/img/tw_circle_hover2.png" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/" class="social"><img src="files/img/yt_circle.png" style="top:100px" data-src="files/img/yt_circle_hover2.png" /></a></td>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/" class="social"><img src="files/img/sndcl_circle.png" style="top:100px" data-src="files/img/sndcl_circle_hover2.png" /></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's what I built so far:

```
$(".social").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

But unfortunately `$(this)` doesn't seem to target the correct element.

Here's a JsFiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/918/** I created. At the left you can see a single image. The change of src works on hover but doesn't go back to original src when mouseleaving.

Comment: Aren't you modifying the original src attribute to something new on hover? How do you plan to restore it? In the mouseleave function you are setting the src to itself which has been overwritten from mouseenter.

Comment: @Satyajit Please elaborate an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve the original src URL. You could do it like this:

```
$(".social").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).data("original-src", $(this).attr("src"))
            .fadeOut(250, function () {
                $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
            }).fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("original-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

The bug is when you trigger `mouseLeave`, you set the `src` back to the `src` it already is (the faded out image).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/920/

Comment: I choose the same solution :)

Comment: Thanks! Last thing: where should I put the stop(). to avoid the continous fade in/out when mouse entering/leaving multiple times?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno I would probably use `fadeTo` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/924/ and I would consider hooking into the hover event if that is what you really want.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Right, that is one of the problems with using the fade effects. Each time you add an effect, it goes onto a queue that jQuery processes. You can call `stop()` to abort the queue but it still won't get you what you want. I'd suggest asking another question outlining what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the old source in a variable and use that to update the source on `mouseleave`. This means that you don't have to query the DOM an extra time.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/HpmN7/923/))

```
var oldsrc;
$(".social").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        oldsrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", oldsrc);
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/2knt67u1/1/

```
$(".social").mouseover(function () {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var dataSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('data-src');
    $(this).fadeOut(250,function(){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',dataSrc);
        $(this).find('img').attr('data-src',src);
    });
    $(this).fadeIn(250);
});
$(".social").mouseout(function () {
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var dataSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('data-src');
    $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", dataSrc);
        $(this).find('img').attr('data-src',src);
    });
    $(this).fadeIn(250);
});
```

Hope it helps you ;-)